# VBA/SQL missing operator in query expression 'Count (distinct)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a query that is inserted in my VBA code and I'm getting a similar missing an operator message. Here is the query:

```
SELECT mtn.*  
FROM ( 
SELECT PATIENT_KEY, RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY 
FROM [claim_detail$] 
WHERE CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD IN ('82330', '82374', '82435', '82565', '82947', '84132', '84295', '84520') 
GROUP BY PATIENT_KEY, RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD) = 8) AS pat_matches 
INNER JOIN [claim_detail$] mtn ON 
mtn.PATIENT_KEY = pat_matches.PATIENT_KEY AND 
mtn.RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY = pat_matches.RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY 
WHERE mtn.CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD IN ('82330', '82374', '82435', '82565', '82947', '84132', '84295', '84520');
```

It is inserted in the code as:

```
query = "SELECT mtn.* " &_
"FROM ( " &_
"SELECT PATIENT_KEY, RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY " &_
"FROM [claim_detail$] " &_
"WHERE CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD IN ('82330', '82374', '82435', '82565', '82947', '84132', '84295', '84520') " &_
"GROUP BY PATIENT_KEY, RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD) >= 8) AS pat_matches " &_
"INNER JOIN [claim_detail$] mtn ON " &_
"mtn.PATIENT_KEY = pat_matches.PATIENT_KEY AND " &_
"mtn.RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY = pat_matches.RENDERING_PROVIDER_KEY " &_
"WHERE mtn.CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD IN ('82330', '82374', '82435', '82565', '82947', '84132', '84295', '84520');"
```

The message I'm getting is

Microsoft Access Database Engine (91, 2) : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(DISTINCT CPT_HCPS_PROC_CD) = 8'.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT)` isn't available in access, you need a subquery.

Comment: Thanks. Even when I removed the DISTINCT, I got the following error message: "Microsoft Access Database Engine (91, 2) : No value given for one or more required parameters."

Comment: That typically indicates a misspelled field name.